# Best way of using static html in Angular + Asp.Net MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to show some static html in my angular application.

For example popup with share buttons - I don't need server data there. So, normally, when you use MVC, you should create a .cshtml view, map it to a controller action and get this content by url route (http://example.com/ajax/share-popup).

Is it ok to create common .html files instead of .cshtml and access it like a physical file http://example.com/views/common/shared-popup.html ?

Thanks.

Comment: if there is nothing sensitive in it, there should be no reason to have to use the extra overhead of server framework to deliver simple html templates

Comment: You can create template inside script tag not need to create a file (that's when you're using a router) or just render your html, make it hidden and show it up when needed.